# How to insert a for loop in a CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop

I have the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  "col1" text NOT NULL,
  "col2" text,
do $$
begin
   for cnt in 0..10 loop
"person.position."+ values(cnt) +".tarif" text,
"brief.person.position"+ values(cnt) +".text" text,
"brief.person.position." + values(cnt) + ".year" year,
"brief.person.position." + values(cnt) + ".rechnungsbetrag" float,
"brief.person.position." + values(cnt)+ ".leistung" text
   end loop;
end; $$;
  );
```

but it throws me an syntax error at the `do`...

What I want to achieve is that the table is created with the 11 defined "dynamic values" and two columns, but my syntax doesn't work like that.

This is for PostgreSQL if it matters.

I have no idea how to insert this for loop in the create table statement, help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What would you want to do? I don't think you need to use `for-loop`

Comment: I want to make columns with `brief.person.position.[number incremented from 0 to 10 here].differentstaticnameshere` to make a new table

Comment: You can't include a PL/pgSQL DO block as part of a DDL statement. You are looking for [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).  However, the whole table structure looks wrong. More often than not, "numbered" columns are a sign of a bad data model and those "columns" should in fact be rows. Also using column names that require double quotes is also discouraged.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your comment. We actually want to import data for this anonymization tool named `datanymizer` and we thought this was the best way to do. How do we accomplish this with rows?